# Efficient intersection of linear subspaces? How to solve a big nonlinear least squares with linear constraints?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, constraints

Problem:

I want to solve a big linearly constrained nonlinear least squares problem. The number of unknowns is between millions and billions. In terms of cost functions, the Hessian would be pretty big and dense. But it's not too difficult to compute the cost function's gradients at particular points.

The linear constraint can be represented as an *intersection* of two linear subspaces. Let's call them *A* and *B*. Nice properties of *A* and *B* are that I'm able to *efficiently* perform an *orthogonal* projection into either of these subspaces. But they are not necessarily orthogonal to each other. So, if given a vector *g* I wouldn't know to how to efficiently compute an orthogonal projection of *g* into the *intersection* of *A* and *B*.

But... if I knew how to do that I could use this kind of projection on the cost function's gradient so that a gradient-based solver would never take any steps that violate the linear constraints.

Do you see a way to efficiently perform such an orthogonal projection into the *intersection* of *A* and *B*?

I'm also open to other suggestions of how to solve this problem in a different way. I've recently stumbled upon the "Augmented Lagrangian method" which appears to be useful. Any (other) suggestions would be welcome!

My last resort would be to use this projection trick only for one subspace and "move" the remaining linear constraints into the cost function (--> penalty method).

The solver I've been using successfully so far (for similar but *un*constrained problems) is the L-BFGS.

Comment: You don't need to be able to project onto $A\cap B$ to efficiently minimize $f(x)$ subject to $x\in A\cap B$. You could, for instance, use a forward-backward type algorithm and iterate something like
$x_{n+1}=(P_A+P_B)/2 \circ (x_n-\gamma \nabla f(x_n)),$ where $\gamma$ is between $0$ and $2/L$ and $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $\nabla f$ and $P_C$ is the projection onto $C$. This works when $A$ and $B$ are closed and your problem is sufficiently qualified (i.e. a solution exists, $f$ is convex, lsc, proper, etc)

Comment: Thank you, @Zim, for taking the time to comment.I guess by $C$ you refer to $A \cap B$, right? And (P_A + P_B)/2 is a function that averages the individual projections? havn't heard about "forward-backward type algorithms".

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant for $C$. A nice fact about $(P_A+P_B)/2$ (in fact, any convex combination of $P_A$ and $P_B$) is: even though it is rarely the projection onto $C$, its fixed point set is equal to $C$ whenever $C\neq\varnothing$. Also, $(P_A+P_B)/2$ is firmly nonexpansive, which is one of the main forces behind the proof of convergence for the forward-backward iteration. A good reference text on the algorithm would be Bauschke & Combettes' book, although that can be a bit dense. You may also want to look into block-iterative variants of the algorithm, due to your large-scale problem.